# How to reboot morethan one remote system?

Tags: command-line, software-center, python

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. I need to reboot multiple systems at a time from my Ubuntu machine.Tell me the way to reboot multiple systems at a time

Comment: You have tagged your post with python. Do you want how to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Cluster SSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/), which can connect  to multiple systems via *ssh*.

Once connected, it executes commands on all systems  simultaneously, including the reboot command when provided.

*Cluster SSH* opens an xterm per connection, hence it will not be useful if number of systems exceeds 10.

For more details, see [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/413853-managing-multiple-linux-servers-with-clusterssh) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access to the remote machine and have same user (for example root) on them use the following shell program:

```
for remote_ip in <ip1> <ip2> <ip3> ...
do
ssh root@$remote_ip reboot
done
```

And if you have different users on different machines:

```
for remote_machine in <user1@remote_ip1> <user2@remote_ip2> <user3@remote_ip3> ...
do
ssh $remote_machine reboot
done
```

Comment: what to do without asking password while ssh run remote system

Comment: For that each remote system has to be setup for an [ssh login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) from your system.